# Dynamic call store procedure from context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In code we found a lot of duplicate code that call function from Context then return a list result. If result is null, return null. Otherwise, return list result.

```
    public static IList<RemittanceDetail> GetDetails()
    {
        var context = StartupBusinessLogic.CreateContext();

        var sourceResult = context.SP_GetRemittanceDetails();

        if (sourceResult == null)
            return null;

        IList<RemittanceDetail> result = new List<RemittanceDetail>();
        Mapper.Map(sourceResult, result);

        return result;
    }

    public static IList<PaymentType> GetPaymentTypes()
    {
        var context = StartupBusinessLogic.CreateContext();

        var sourceResult = context.SP_GetPaymentTypes();

        if (sourceResult == null)
            return null;

        IList<PaymentType> result = new List<PaymentType>();
        Mapper.Map(sourceResult, result);

        return result;
    }
```

Could we create a generic method to handle this task? My concern is how to call dynamic function of context

```
context.SP_GetPaymentTypes()
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Thank @AndreasNiedermair, I noticed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have right now is that you're using 2 functions to fetch some data in my opinion, why don't you move all the logic from your current functions to `SP_GetRemittanceDetails` and `SP_GetPaymetTypes`. In those functions you should just return a list, by calling `.ToList()` method in the end of your query. It could look like this:

```
public IList<PaymentType> SP_GetPaymentTypes()
{
    using(var ctx = new StartupBusinessLogic())
    {
        var query = ctx. blablabla
        query = query.*more filtering*
        return query.ToList();
    }
 }
```

2 remarks with this:

1) It's better to call your context in a `using` statement, because at the moment you're not disposing of your context which is bad.

2) When your query result contains nothing, and you call ToList(), the List you return will automatically be null, so the checks and use of Mapping function becomes obsolete.

To convert the IQueryable to IList you can use extension methods:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IList<T> GetList<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do

```
var context = StartupBusinessLogic.CreateContext();
var sourceResult = context.SP_GetRemittanceDetails().GetList();
```

And the result will be of type `Ilist<T>`

Comment: Thank for your answering. They pull data and return to UI, then UI will process next. I cannot put the UI process into BL. My concern is, if I have 2 functions do the same steps and slightly different at one step. Could I turn it to generic? In this case is calling store procedure

Comment: I assume `SP_GetRemittanceDetails` return `IQueryable`?

Comment: Hi Alex, it returns List<T>. But even SP_GetRemittanceDetails returns IQueryable, I have nothing to do with that list. I just only should return to the caller

Comment: I edited my answer, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: You're welcome, accept my answer if you'd be so kind :)